# How to filter features in a layer?

Tags: qgis, postgis, query, rendering, filter

I am trying to display certain features in a shapefile-based layer using QGIS. I have found the subset function in the properties panel, which does exactly what i want, but is too tedious given that I have to manually sift through a large number of features. Is there a quicker way to do this?

I am using both shapefiles and postGIS
best, 
dietmar

Answer (score 14):

In QGIS you should be able to filter your data with an SQL expression in the Query Builder dialog.  Just right click your layer in the table of contents and select "Query" ("Filter..." in the more recent versions).

Comment: In recent versions the dialog option "Query" has been renamed to "Filter..."

Answer (score 5):

Tested on [QGIS 3.10.2-A Coruna](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/)

**How to apply a filter**
* Right-click on the layer listed in panel `Layers`
* Choose `Filter...`
* The window `Query Builder` is displayed

**How to build a query in Query Builder**
* Double click on a field in `Fields` list
* Select `All` in `Values`
* Choose a operator from `Operators`
* Double click on a value in `Values` list
* Your expression is shown at the bottom of the window
* Click `Test` to have a preview of how many rows are returned
* Click `OK` to apply the filter
* The layer is displayed according to the filter applied (you see a filter icon aside the layer name in panel `Layers`)

Comment: I regularly use the Filter feature in QGIS. However in a new project I have just started, I have layers where there is no Filter option available, and the Layer > Filter menu option is greyed out. Does anyone know why a certain layer might not be filterable? I have not come across this before.

Comment: @FrancisBarton, in my case I had to disable editing.

Comment: In my case, the "toggle editing" menu item is greyed out, and the entire Edit menu is similarly greyed out and unavailable.