# Creating new layer out of shapefile after selecting attributes using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, ogr, fields-attributes

I'm currently writing my Thesis about QGIS where it is my task to create a map of Austrias motorways (roads with the type A and B3**). I am working with a shapefile where all roads are so I selected the ones I need by looking for attributes. Now my problem is that I cannot save them as a new layer. As it comes to saving it the following message shows up:

```
"Export in Vektordatei schlug fehl. Fehler: Layererzeugung schlug fehl (OGR-Fehler: Failed to open Shapefile `Autobahn_Test1.shp'.)"
```

This pretty much says that the export to a vector-format has failed.

```
Error: Generating a layer has failed (OGR-error).
```

What else can I try to make this work?

Comment: Perhaps use a query for the layer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25963/how-to-filter-features-in-a-layer. The most likely cause of failing to save is to have bad characters in the file name, the name must not contain non-alphanumeric characters except for underscore, what is the file name you're trying to save?

Comment: Autobahn_Test1.shp is a valid filename, but did you perhaps accidently try to save at a location without write-permission??

Comment: Did you perhaps try to overwrite your shapefile wich is openend in QGIS? I never observed a fail when trying to write shapefiles from QGIS ...

Comment: Consider to provide some screenshots for better explanation of the steps you carried out...

Comment: I first had to save it as a layer definition file and then i could continue saving it as a new layer.