# How to filter style to display only where data in one column in the attribute table is not the same as the data in another column

Tags: qgis, style, filter

I have a .shp with attribute data containing current zone, current code, proposed zone, proposed code, final zone, final code etc.

I want to duplicate this layer and style it to display a black outline style only where there is a mismatch between data in columns, this in effect creates a map that identifies where there is a change proposed to draw attention to these areas.

Comment: What GIS software are you using? Do you want to create a new shapefile with just the mismatched polygons or display the existing polygons that only mismatch?

Comment: I'm using QGIS 2.18.21, the latter, just need to filter it to display polygons where there is a change.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25963/how-to-filter-features-in-a-layer should point you in the right direction.. your query should be something like field_1 <> field_2; Shapefiles aren't case sensitive. Consider adding a QGIS tag to your question to get the right kind of attention.

Comment: Thanks, that actually worked perfectly 'field_1 <> field_2' problem solved! looks fantastic

Comment: Please post the solution as a well-formatted answer to this question, including some explanation/screenshots if possible.

Comment: @Michael Stimson, your one comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is how its done.

I will provide further screenshots of the outcome when the info is no longer confidential

[image: Filter content]