# QGIS attribute table doesn't show all items

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have a situation, where the Show All Items is clicked, but the filter appears despite of this option.

[image]

Is it some bug?

https://issues.qgis.org/issues/12318

How can I make all of them visible?

Comment: The features are filtered with SQL-like query: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/25969/35561

Answer (score 2):

As @ComradeChe says the filter is at the layer level (dictate witch feature are "loaded" in QGIS), not attribute table level (where you can choose witch of the "loaded" show in the current view of the attribute table).

If you look in the layer panel you should see a funnel icon next to the layer name, click on it to access the Query Builder where you will be able to clear (or edit) the filter.

If you dont want to loose the filter you may comment it by adding -- at the beginning of the expression, this will deactivate the expression but it will still be available in the query builder.

[image]