# Filtering which points to display using expressions in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, expression, filter, visualisation

I have a load of points loaded in as a CSV file. I want to show only certain points based on their name, e.g. only value1, value4 and value8, the field name is `"Drilled ID"`.

I have gone to symbology, then categorised and tried this:

```
"Drilled ID" = 'value1' or 'value4' or 'value8'
```

Then hit classify, but it doesn't display value1, value4 and value8 only.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Switch to Rule-based and use
`"Drilled ID" IN ('value1', 'value4','value8')`

Consider setting a [filter](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25963/how-to-filter-features-in-a-layer) if you don't want to display anything else.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Use either

```
"Drilled ID" in ('value1','value4','value8')
```

Or

```
"Drilled ID" = 'value1' or "Drilled ID" = 'value4' or "Drilled ID" = 'value8'
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of symbology, use [Provider Feature filter](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#source-properties): open layer properties > Source > Query Builder and add this query:

```
"Drilled ID"  IN  ('value1', 'value4', 'value8')
```

Be aware that your field name contains a space. That might cause problems with CSV. Better stick to field names like `"DrilledID"` or `"Drilled_ID"`.